# Find the image of line that go through zero under the exponential function

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to find the image of $f(z)=e^z$ while $ z \in \mathbb{C}$. z is a line that go through the origin.

I know that $z=x+iy$ while $x,y$ real numbers. Writing $$e^{z} = e^x(\cos y + i\sin y),$$

now the meaning of the set is that $y=nx \quad n \in \mathbb{R}$

so I substitute this condition and get
$$e^x(\cos nx + i\sin nx)= e^x(\cos x + i\sin x)^n.$$

1. Is my method correct?
2. What is this set? can I say that $e^x(\cos nx + i\sin nx)$ is a circle with radius $e^x$? how does it look on the plane?

Comment: Try thinking about what $e^x$ and $e^{i nx}$ separately do as $x$ increases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your parameterization is quite right. You have $y = nx$, $n\in\mathbb{R}$, so your set is $\{(x,nx): n\in \mathbb{R}\}\subset\mathbb{R}^2$. But you're paramterizing $z$ a line through the origin in the complex plane. Your line through the origin in the real plane is a different set.

You want to find the image of a line through the origin in the complex plane. We can parametrize this as $z(r) = re^{i\theta}$, where $r\in \mathbb{R}$ and $\theta$ is constant. So $$f(z(r)) = e^{re^{i\theta}} = (e^{e^{i\theta}})^r.$$ Since $\theta$ is fixed $e^{e^{i\theta}}$ is a constant complex number, denote it with say $c$. Then $f(z(r)) = \{c^r: r\in \mathbb{R}\}$.

Comment: so the image is not going through the origin? im not sure I understand the big picture here

Comment: If your image contains the origin then $e^z=0$ at that point. Try for yourself to find a $z$ solving this equation to see where the difficulty lies. Why do you think it has to contain the origin?